# I need to query a result from query in SQL

Tags: mysql

i have this query :

```
SELECT object, date, MAX(min) as max FROM total GROUP BY obect, date
```

and gives me this table result:

| object | date | max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2021-09-09 | 660 |
| 2 | 2021-09-11 | 555 |
| 3 | 2021-09-09 | 555 |
| 4 | 2021-09-09 | 630 |
| 5 | 2021-09-10 | 555 |

now  i need to query this result with this query:

```
SELECT sum(max), object, FORM total GROUP BY object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the first Select as basis for the second

```
SELECT sum(max), object
FROM
(SELECT object, date, MAX(min) as max FROM total GROUP BY obect, date) t1
GROUP By object
```